# Does the EF-S 18-55 STM make noise when it autofocuses?

Tags: autofocus, focus-motor

I'm planning on buying a Canon 70D with the kit lens, an 18-55mm IS STM lens, to film tutorial-style videos (and for other purposes as well). I know that sometimes you can hear cameras autofocusing in video. My question is, will you be able to hear the autofocus with the kit STM lens, or should I buy a different lens that will make less noise, like a 50mm f/1.8 STM lens? I know that STM lenses are supposed to be near-silent but I really don't know anything about DSLR cameras or lenses, as I am a pure beginner. Therefore, some educated advice would be MUCH appreciated!

Comment: Video questions are off-topic here, but can be asked at [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: If you want to film tutorial-style videos, you might want to consider an external microphone that attaches to your clothes, or a desktop microphone. In this case, the mic is away from the camera and shouldn't pick up any focusing sounds

Answer (score 3):

The 18-55 STM uses the virtually silent Lead-Screw Type STM. You will not hear it auto focus.

There are two types of STM auto focus:

The 24mm STM, 40mm STM, and 50mm STM all use the Gear-Type STM which is not all that silent or fast.

All the other EF-S STM lenses use Lead-Screw Type STM which is virtually silent and also very fast.

[image]

Comment: Why two different systems? Why not use Lead-Screw for all STM lenses?

Comment: I think it is simply a size issue. The Gear Type STM looks smaller, but it may be a cost issue as well since all the Gear Type STM lenses are very cheap to buy.

Comment: As far as cost goes, the 18-55 is the cheapest of all. As far as size goes the 50MM and the 18-55 are not really that different. Anyway I did not know about the two STM systems. Thanks!

Comment: The EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM is not that cheap. It it sells for $249 at B&H: http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/945061-REG/canon_8114b002_ef_s_18_55mm_f_3_5_5_6_is.html